# Modificar o intervalo de um JSlider

Tags: java, swing, jslider

Em meu projeto tenho um JSlider, que o seu valor mínimo é 0 e o seu valor máximo é 10. Gostaria de modifica-lo para que o seu intervalo seja de dois em dois números, assim somente sendo possível selecionar/mostrar valores pares. No momento, estou usando o seguinte código para fazer isso:

```
    int sliderValor = sliderFim.getValue();   

    //se não for par
    if((sliderValor % 2 != 0))
    {
        sliderFim.setValue(++sliderValor);
    }
    lblFim.setText(Integer.toString(sliderValor));
```

Existe alguma maneira melhor ou mais recomendada para fazer isso?

Comment: acredito que seja setStep(2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Com o comando abaixo:

```
slider.setMajorTickSpacing(2);
```

Isso definirá o tamanho máximo de espaçamento entre os "ticks" do JSlider, mas ainda será possivel selecionar valores não pares entre os eles. Adicionando o trecho abaixo, vai exibir os valores de 2 em 2 e restringir o movimento do snap a somente andar em cada um dos marcadores:

```
// define o espaçamento entre os ticks    
slider.setMajorTickSpacing(2);
// desenham os valores dos ticks
// abaixo do slider
slider.setPaintTicks(true);
slider.setPaintLabels(true);
// restringe o snap a parar
// somente sobre os ticks
slider.setSnapToTicks(true);
```

Veja funcionando:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]